# Insert empty line in select query result

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

I want to get data from database in code behind c#  in asp.net.
I am trying to get two columns in one result and put it in one gridview column.
How to insert blank line between these two columns? 
The command text is

```
"Select question + ': '+ answer from Questions .... ".
```

Is there any way to get the result like this:

question:

answer (in new line).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What you want to achieve is "result formatting" which is not primary purpose of the database. Much better if you will do formatting in the view, client side etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to create one coulmn from 2 column with question `:` on the first line and answer on the next. Then this might do the trick for you.

```
SELECT CONCAT(question, ':', CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) , answer) as QuesAns From TableName
```

or

```
SELECT (question + ':' + (CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)) + answer) as QuesAns From TableName
```

Comment: you better give it a temporary name (alias) to make it more readable. and he cant set field name in GridView designer without an alias.

Comment: @Badiparmagi Well that is a nice idea. Lemme implement

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I think the query now get the right result but the problem still to show two lines in the gridview.

Comment: Happy to help @ghadeerdarwesh :) You are welcome. Another way of saying thanks on SO would be an upvote